# Pandas: flatten data from inconsistent rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input Excel spreadsheet like this:

```
key  | value | other data
------------------------- ...
k1   | v1    | d1
     | v2    |
     | v3    |
k2   | v2    | d2
     | v5    |
k3   | v1    | d3
```

Values are stored in an empty, except for the value column, row directly below the row with the matching key and there can be arbitrary number of values bound to the key, however highly unlikely more than three. All keys are unique, 'other data' may be missing or be repeated, there is around a dozen of values and thousands of data rows.

I need to convert the input table to the following format:

```
k1   | v1,v2,v3 | d1 | ...
k2   | v2,v5    | d2 | ...
k3   | v1       | d3 | ...
```

I have solved this problem with openpyxl and a trivial iterative algorithm and I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this using Pandas' DataFrame manipulation facilities? I searched for Pandas data manipulation tutorials, but most of what I could find use `groupby()` and `agg()` which is seemingly not my case, since I have no column I can aggregate on and can only depend on the key being consistently unique.

Head-on solution, I used for now:

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('in.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

row_data = None
out_list = list()
i = 2
while i < ws.max_row + 1:
    if ws[i][0].value is not None:
        if row_data is not None:
            out_list += [row_data]
        row_data = list(ws[i])
    else:
        row_data[1].value = f'{row_data[1].value}' + f',{ws[i][1].value}'
    i += 1

out_list += [list(ws[ws.max_row])]   # append the last row to the output

wb_out = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws_out = wb_out.active

for row in out_list:
    ws_out.append([cell.value for cell in row])

wb_out.save('out.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas way of doing this considering the excel looks like below:

[image]

```
df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\path\excelfile.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet_Name')
df=(df.groupby(df.key.ffill()).agg({'value':lambda x: ','.join(x),'other data':'first'})
                                                                .reset_index())
```

---

```
  key     value other data
0  k1  v1,v2,v3         d1
1  k2     v2,v5         d2
2  k3        v1         d3
```